# Explain these lines of code in Scala

Tags: scala

I'm trying to understand exactly how the following code snippet works, in particular line 2, `Seq(JsString(bar), _*)`, and line 3, `must_`, syntax is puzzling to me

```
val foo = (Json.parse(contentAsString(result)    
val Seq(JsString(bar), _*) = (foo \\ "bar")
bar must_== "crazy"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Line 2 is a pattern match, but using `val` syntax.  `foo \\ "bar"` returns a `Seq`, which you can match on;

```
Seq(JsString(bar), _*)
```

means that the item must match to a `Seq` and the first item must be a `JsString` whose content we will call `bar`, and we don't care about the rest (`_*`).  Normally you'd see this like so:

```
(foo \\ "bar") match {
  case Seq(JsString(bar), _*) =>  // do something with bar
  ...
}
```

but it turns out that you can initialize `val`s this way also.

Also, `must_==` is a method name (methods can be alphanumeric followed by an underscore followed by symbols) for some testing framework.  I forget which.  But there almost certainly is an implicit conversion from whatever to tested-whatever, and tested-whatever has the `must_==` method.

Comment: THanks, that explains things. Question, so `bar` got set as a val as a side effect? And `_*` ignores the rest of the `JsString` matches?

Comment: @Bob - Not exactly as a side effect--it's just another way to get your hands on a variable name that you can refer to.  `_*` matches anything, so yes, that effectively ignores the rest.